# Unable to deploy talend code to nexus using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, talend

Can any help me out to understand the error message.

Basically my context is to deploy code to nexus, there are multiple thing in my deployment process some things are getting deploying and some thing are not getting deployed.

```
[INFO] CI Codes Master 7.0.1 .............................. FAILURE [  0.466 s]
[INFO] CI Routines ........................................ SUCCESS [  3.743 s]
[INFO] CI demo1-0.1.0 (0.1,Job Designs) 0.1.0 ............. SUCCESS [  1.200 s]
```

Jenkin Goals and Options:
[image: Jenkin Goals and Options]

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.talend:ci.builder:7.0.1:generate (default) on project code.Master: Fail to execute command: InitLocalCommand initLocal: null -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.talend:ci.builder:7.0.1:generate (default) on project code.Master: Fail to execute command: InitLocalCommand initLocal
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
    [ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Talend\7.0.1\ci_builder\commandline-workspace\CI\poms\pom.xml to org.example.ci/code.Master/7.0.1/code.Master-7.0.1.pom
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Thanks in advance.

This pom file i am using for my jobs

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>code.Master</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>CI Codes Master</name>
  <url>http://www.talend.org/</url>
  <modules>
    <module>code/routines</module>
    <module>jobs/process/demo1_0.1</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <talend.project.name>CI</talend.project.name>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
              <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ci-builder</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
            <artifactId>ci.builder</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: There is an issue in your pom file: `Fail to execute command: InitLocalCommand initLocal: null`....

Comment: @khmarbaise i have add my pom file in comments section, if possible can you verify it. Can you think of any other reasons. Interesting thing is that i have client desktop and my personal laptop it is working on my personal laptop but not on my client desktop i am using same pom file for both. Thanks for you help

Comment: Based on your pom file the plugin ci.builder ...is the problem. Cause the parameters for the plugin are not correct. You need to check the docs for the plugin...